# How to get the frame (origin, Size) of every visible windows on the active space?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm trying to figure out how to get the frame of all visible windows.
I tried the following code, but it only works for the app itself other windows report {0,0,0,0}

```
   NSArray *windowArray =  [NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions:NSWindowNumberListAllApplications | NSWindowNumberListAllSpaces];
for(NSNumber *number in windowArray){
    NSLog(@"Window number: %@", number);
    NSWindow *window = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] windowWithWindowNumber:[number intValue]];
    NSLog(@"Window: %@", NSStringFromRect( [[window contentView] frame]));
}
```

Sample code is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
    NSMutableArray *windows = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);

for (NSDictionary *window in windows) {
    NSString *name = [window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowName" ];
    CGRect bounds;
    CGRectMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation((CFDictionaryRef)[window objectForKey:@"kCGWindowBounds"], &bounds);
    NSLog(@"%@: %@",name,NSStringFromRect(bounds));            
}
```

Comment: You should not assume that `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` returns an NSMutableArray, and since it is a Copy function, you need to either release the array or use `__bridge_transfer`.

Comment: I've also been working on this, and it helped alot. I needed to find the enclosing rectangle of all the active windows of a given application pid.

Comment: First get a window list of every windows in this session (CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo) - on and off screen. You can get the pid of the owner (kCGWindowOwnwerPID) of the any window and then match that with your pid. When you have a match, there is a function that returns exactly your needed NSRect. (CGRectMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation for kCGWindowBounds)

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an `NSWindow` for a window of another application.  In general, you can't access the objects of other applications except through an interface that they cooperate with, like scripting.

You can get what you're looking for using the [Quartz Window Services (a.k.a. CGWindowList) API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html).

I'm not at all sure that the window numbers returned by Cocoa are the same as the window numbers used by that API.  In fact, the docs for `-[NSWindow windowNumber]` specifically say "note that this isn’t the same as the global window number assigned by the window server". I'm note sure to what use you can put the window numbers returned by `+[NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions:]` which are not for your application's windows.